# How to convert List<Integer> to Integer[] in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I was trying to convert an `ArrayList` of `Integer` to `Integer[]`

```
Integer[] finalResult = (Integer[]) result.toArray();
```

but I got an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

Help me out please.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the version of [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) that accepts a generic argument:

```
Integer[] finalResult = new Integer[result.size()];
result.toArray(finalResult);
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
Integer[] finalResult = result.toArray(new Integer[result.size()]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot cast `List` to an array, because a `List` is not an array. Here are two methods for converting a `List<Integer>` to an `Integer[]`.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
Integer[] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
Integer[] arr2 = list.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new); // Java 8 only
```

Answer (score 3):

[List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) returns an Object array. Use [List.toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) instead:

```
Integer[] finalResult = (Integer[]) result.toArray(new Integer[result.size()]);
```

Comment: No need for the cast. The return type is already `T[]`, which gets bound at compile time to `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize array. Try like this

```
Integer[] finalResult = new Integer[result.size()];
finalResult = result.toArray(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in multiple ways:

1st method

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

T [] countries = list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
```

example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("India");
list.add("Switzerland");
list.add("Italy");
list.add("France");

String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

2nd method

```
Foo[] array = new Foo[list.size()];
list.toArray(array); // fill the array
```

3rd method

```
List<Integer> list = ...;
int[] array = new int[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) array[i] = list.get(i);
```

you can also find some example codes here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_toarray.htm or http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/list/java-list-to-array-example/

Comment: You need to get rid of `myArray = new String();` in the 4th method.

Comment: I got to know a new method for Java 8-list.stream from your answer. +1'd your answer for that

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are using `list.size()` inside `toArray()` method for some reason which isn't needed at all. You can just pass an empty integer array with size 0.

It is simple and easy. Take a look:

```java
List<Integer> yourList = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Integer[] intArray = yourList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```